# Editing my answer based on other answers

Tags: discussion

Is it acceptable to edit my answer to include something said in another answer? This problem came up in this question: [What is the best technique for long-exposure photography in good light?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1402/tips-for-a-long-exposure). My understanding is that we want the first answer to "say it all". What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's acceptable, but for more significant "somethings" I'd consider giving credit to the contributor who gave you the idea.

Comment: +1. The point is to provide good answers. If people have to wade through multiple answers to get a complete picture, that's contrary to that goal. However, credit is important too. Now the answer incorporating the other ideas will accrue reputation, but summarizing other answers is work that IMO deserves such credit.

Comment: +1. I wouldn't create a second "compilation answer", however, if there was already a decent one established and up-voted. We're not really about competing, just getting a good answer to every question, and recognising the people who make an effort.

Answer (score 1):

The software on which the site is based has proven itself where there is a single correct answer. If you've skimmed over a side detail, then I would encourage editing to include more into your answer. It's worth remembering that all content provided is licenced as [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/) with [attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/), however.

For questions that are inherently subjective (i.e. there is no single correct answer), then perhaps we should be (strongly) encouraging the asker to flag it as community wiki - I believe then it removes the question from your percentage of accepted answers too.